# Leading zeros after exporting to csv from SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, export, export-to-csv, leading-zero

I have a SQL script which outputs data to csv file. The script works fine however the leading zero is stripped from the phone number when I export to csv.

SQL:

```
SELECT RTRIM(Mobile_Telephone) AS Mobile_Number FROM TABLE
```

Datatype: char(20), not null

I am exporting data to csv using SSIS package

Can you please advise how I can preserve Leading zeros after exporting to csv.

Thanks
Aruna

Comment: Can you share your SQL script (or a relevant snippet)? What data type is your phone number column? what do you use to export/convert the result to csv?

Comment: @Pidon please see edits above

Comment: I have no experience with SSIS but maybe these links can help: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic674975-148-1.aspx https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8c5e242-e982-4cbb-8f58-effca31ea022/leading-zero-to-numbers-in-csv-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 1):

Try using **CONCAT** syntax after SELECT

```
SELECT CONCAT('Phone Number Value') FROM table
```

See if it helps

Comment: I tried CONCAT('RTRIM(STUDstudent.STUD_Home_Telephone_No)') AS Home_Telephone but get an error: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Try converting your telephone no into string value instead of a number, see if it helps.